# Azure DevOps Webhooks (Service Hooks) Missing Fields like Description or Repro Steps

Tags: azure-devops, devops, webhooks, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on ASP.NET Core 5 project, which will use a subscription to my organization's Azure DevOps Service Hooks (Webhooks). I will analyze event payload's data (and metadata).

I checked what event payloads contains from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#workitem.updated

And also downloaded this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.vsts

But there is a problem. I cannot find (in the docs and also in the NuGet package) Work Item's "Description" field or Bug's "Repro Steps" fields. These two fields are most important fields from payload for my project.

Are these fields hidden somewhere? Or is possible to include these fields in payload?

Answer (score 1):

After querying [Work Item Types Field - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types%20field/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api which used to get a list of fields for a work item type with detailed references.

```
 {
      "alwaysRequired": false,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "allowedValues": [],
      "dependentFields": [],
      "referenceName": "System.Description",
      "name": "Description",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/fields/System.Description"
    },
```

The referenceName of Description field should be `System.Description`.

As you have pointed, seems this is not include in webhook event payload.

You may have to use work item Rest API to query corresponding info.

Comment: Okay I understand that it cannot be that simple. So I cant use webhooks and I need to use Rest API to retrieve these fields. That's bit complicated, because I think that I will need to include some values for security (I think oauth2?). Please which values should I ask from my organization's owner for authorizing the requests and how to authorize them?

How to retrieve concrete Work Item's field values by the tutorial from the link you provided? Did not I need rather [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) ?

Comment: @Anakkiin Yes, it's that Rest API. Azure DevOps Services uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol to authorize your app for a user and generate an access token. Use this token when you call the REST APIs from your app. For more details you could refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops . Just an access token, make sure that token have permission of work items.