# Azure DevOps Rest API get additional fields from Work Item (or Bug)

Tags: .net, rest, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, field

I am working on ASP.NET (Core) 5 project, that will use subscription to my organization's Azure DevOps Service Hooks (Webhooks). I will analyze event payload's data (and metadata).

As I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65002253/14702022) there is not possible to retrieve Work Item's "Description" field and Bug's "Repro Steps" field through Webhook's payload. So I will need to use Rest API, but I never worked with Azure DevOps web API and my project was not ready for this yet. And I am also need to authorizing request (oauth2?), so I will need help also with this.

Will be [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) enough for my needs?

I think that my requests will need to include some values for security (I think oauth2?). Please which values should I ask from my organization's owner for authorizing the requests and how to authorize them?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to checkout below answer. How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Above [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api will include the Work Item's "Description" field and Bug's "Repro Steps" field in the response result. You can use this rest api.

You can also use [Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=azure-devops-dotnet) library. See the `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` object in [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet).

You can get the workitem's fields using `GetWorkItemAsync` Method. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.getworkitemasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet).

If you want to use OAuth 2.0 for authorization. You can check out the document [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) for detailed information.

There are many ways to authenticate your application with Azure DevOps Services. You can check out the examples, and code samples given in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) and choose the right authentication mechanism according to your project.